# Why doesn't my approach solve interval scheduling algorithm?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, greedy

I am working on a code challenge which is a variation of interval scheduling.

**The question is :**

Assume you have a hotel, and you have k beds. You want to host as many customers as possible.

**Input:** 
the first line of input contains two integers n and k (1 ≤ k < n ≤ 100000), the number of potential customers and the number of beds.

Then follow n lines, each containing two integers Xi and Yi, meaning that customer i wants to arrive at time Xi and leave at time Yi. If the staying period of two customers don't overlap with each other, these 2 customers can use the same bed, for example, customer i and j, where  Yi = Xj, they can then use the same bed, as one leaves at the same time as the other arrives. You may assume that 0 ≤ Xi < Yi ≤ 1000000000.

**Output:**
maximum number of customers that can be hosted given the requests.

```
sample input: 
6 2
2 3
5 100
7 8
9 10
1 4
3 100

sample output:
5
```

**My approach:**

```js
//use readline for input handling
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

let numOfLine = 0;
let numOfGuest;
let numOfAvailableBed;
let sessions = [];

rl.on("line", line => {
  let recievedLine = line.split(" ").map(el => {
    return el * 1; // turn input to number
  });

  if (numOfLine === 0) {
    numOfGuest = recievedLine[0];
    numOfAvailableBed = recievedLine[1];
  } else {
    //store all the sessions in sessions array   
    sessions.push(recievedLine);   
  }

  numOfLine++;

  //when this is the last line of input
  if (numOfLine === numOfGuest + 1) {

   //sessions = [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 5, 100 ], [ 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 3, 100 ] ]

  /*I used the following method as a greedy approach:
  sort the sessions array by the **earliest end time**, if it is a draw, it will be then sorted by earliest start time
    */

    sessions = sessions.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[1] < b[1]) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a[1] > b[1]) {
        return 1;
      }
      return a[0] - b[0];
    });

    /*sorted sessions: 
    [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10 ], [ 3, 100 ], [ 5, 100 ] ] 

I then find out the max. number of customers that can stay when the hotel only has 1 room by using a loop and comparing the start time of current session and end time of previous session, if it fits to the schdule, store it in a variable - schedule - which is an object.

then repeat the loop until all the available beds are used up. */
        
    let currentBed = 1;
    let schedule = {};
    let cantHostGuests = [];

    for (let k = currentBed; k <= numOfAvailableBed; k++) {
      schedule[currentBed] = [];
      let previousSessionEndTime = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
        let currentSessionStartTime = sessions[i][0];

        if (previousSessionEndTime <= currentSessionStartTime) {
          //when there is no overlap
          previousSessionEndTime = sessions[i][1];
          schedule[currentBed].push(sessions[i]);
        } else {
          //when there is overlap
          cantHostGuests.push(sessions[i]);
        }
      }

      if (cantHostGuests.length >= 1) {
        sessions = cantHostGuests;
        cantHostGuests = [];
        currentBed += 1;
      }
    }

  /*schedule = 
    {
      '1': [ [ 2, 3 ], [ 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10 ] ],
      '2': [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 5, 100 ] ]
    }
  */    
   
    let numOfGuestHosted = 0;
    for (const bed in schedule) {
      numOfGuestHosted += schedule[bed].length;
    }

    // reset for next test
    sessions = [];
    numOfLine = 0;

    console.log(numOfGuestHosted); //answer
  }
});
```

I created some test data and tested. It works, but it could not pass the test from the code challenge platform, it shows wrong answer, and no other information. So i have no idea why it doesn't work.

Any idea why it fails??

Comment: For a greedy solution, would you not take the longer stays before the shorter ones ?

Comment: @ChrisHall the goal of this problem is to offer beds to as many different customers as possible

Comment: Sorry... must learn not to make assumptions :-(  But, in that case, would you not take the shorter stays before the longer ?

Comment: no sorry, thanks for for your comment. If I handle the shorter stay first, the result will not be maximize in some scenarios. 

for example:
```
Input: 
5 1
1 5
5 8
8 11
7 9
11 12
```
if shorter intervals are handled first, the session 7 9 will be handled first, and since it overlap with 8 10 and 5 8, the ans will be just 3. but actually 4 customers can be hosted

Comment: I have just found a test case that doesn't work with my approach!!!
```Input: 5 2
3 101
1 11
2 10
11 12
10 132```

i got 3 customers { 
1: [2, 10], [11, 12], 
2: [1, 11] 
}, 
but answer should be 1: [2, 10], [10, 132],
2: [1, 11], [11, 12])  , 4 customers

Comment: Well (1) a greedy approach is not always going to give you an absolutely optimal solutions.  But (2) the examples you give suggest that a further heuristic may be to consider how many customers are excluded by choosing customer 'X'.  So, although 7..9 is short, it also excludes 8..10 and 5..8, so is not as good as them together ?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the customers by when they want to *leave* (breaking ties on each order).  Take each customer for whom you have a spare bed.

Before proving that this works, note that this produces a unique solution.

Next, consider the optimal solution that agrees with the solution that this algorithm produces for as long as possible.  If it is this one, then you have an optimal solution.

We will prove by contradiction that that one is this solution.  For if it were not not this solution, then look at the first customer that you turn away that this solution would have kept.  Including that customer could have made you turn away another, but at most one because we have already accounted for what happens with all other customers want to leave earlier.  So trading which you accept results in another optimal solution that agrees with this one for longer - contrary to the hypothesis.